# Show date data in edit form laravel

Tags: php, laravel, date, laravel-5

In edit form laravel, how to show date value in edit form?

```
 <label class="control-label col-md-1">{!! trans('view.dataanggota.form.tgllhr') !!}</label>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="input-icon">
        {!! Form::date('tgllhr', (isset($data->tgllhr) && $data->tgllhr ? $data->tgllhr : date('d-m-Y')), ['class' => 'form-control','id' => 'tgllhr','value' => '$data->tgllhr']) !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```php
{!! Form::date('tgllhr', $data->tgllhr ?? date('d-m-Y'), ['class' => 'form-control','id' => 'tgllhr','value' => '$data->tgllhr']) !!}
```

it will work if you are using php 7.x